# How can I auto-update cordova plugins in a build script?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a multi-cordova project setup in jenkins and therefore the build is scripted, with a structure as follows

```
Cordova/plugins/*my custom plugins*
Cordova/A/... cordova project
Cordova/B/... another cordova project
Cordova/C/... another cordova project
```

My build script, for each project does the following

```
cd A
cordova plugin remove my-custom-plugin
cordova plugin add ../plugins/my-custom-plugin
cd B
cordova plugin remove my-custom-plugin
cordova plugin add ../plugins/my-custom-plugin
cd C
cordova plugin remove my-custom-plugin
cordova plugin add ../plugins/my-custom-plugin
```

But despite the version of `../plugins/my-custom-plugin` being newer, cordova removes the plugin from the platform, but does not remove it from the projects local plugins folder, and when re-adding it uses the version from the projects local plugins folder not the version from the local `../plugin` path.

I suspect this is because config.xml says `^1.0.7` for `my-custom-plugin` which the local version is `1.0.7` the new version in `../plugins/my-custom-plugin` is `1.0.8`.

Is there a way to force the plugin to always update from the `../plugins/my-custom-plugin` version? Preferably something I can do in my build script (bash) that doesn't involve an extra dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps in your special case, but a very nice cli tool for checking versions of plugins and to (auto-) update them is this one:

[cordova-check-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-check-plugins)

Give it a try and check it out.

Comment: I was aware of this option, but didn't want to go down that route as it added another dependency, and felt it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem.

Each time the project is built, it leaves a partial ios platform behind.  I am not sure why that is happening because I don't explicitly `cordova platform add ios`, but there is a reference to ios in config.xml so that may have something to do with it.

Anyway, the next time the project is built, the script removes the plugins then removes the platforms, and the removal of plugins is failing when it tries to remove the plugin from the ios platform because the `PlatformApi` is not available, this means it doesn't get around to doing the `npm uninstall` that it would have, completely removing the plugin.

So, when re-adding, it used the already npm installed version, not the latest version.

The solution was simple.  Remove the platforms first, then remove the plugins.  That way, the ios platform problem can't trip up the plugin removal.

As a bonus, it's quicker doing it that way around.